# index string by character

Tags: python

I need to determine the most frequent character of a list of strings by each index in Python.

Example

list1 = ['one', 'two', 'twin', 'who']

the most frequent character between all the strings at index 0 is 't'
the most frequent character between all the strings at index 1 is 'w'
the most frequent character between all the strings at index 2 is 'o'
the most frequent character between all the strings at index 3 is 'n'(because there is only one character at the index 3

from that I want to create a final string 'twon' which shows the most frequent character of all the strings by each index

how can I perform this on python without importing any library?
thanks

Comment: Please share the code you have tried with, then we can help you troubleshoot any issues you might have with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

list1 = ['one', 'two', 'twin', 'who']

chars = {}
for i, item in enumerate(zip_longest(*list1)):
    set1 = set(item)
    if None in set1:
        set1.remove(None)
    chars[i] = max(set1, key=item.count)
```

Without importing any library:

```py
list1 = ['one', 'two', 'twin', 'who']

width = len(max(list1, key=len))

chars = {}

for i, item in enumerate(zip(*[s.ljust(width) for s in list1])):
    set1 = set(item)
    if ' ' in set1:
        set1.remove(' ')
    chars[i] = max(set1, key=item.count)
```

Output:

`chars`

```py
{
  0: 't',
  1: 'w',
  2: 'o', 
  3: 'n'
}
```

`"".join(chars.values())`

```py
'twon'
```

Comment: How can I perform the same without importing any library? thanks

Comment: @nuovo2000ita I added the `without importing` version!

Comment: You could also use your original solution with `for i, item in enumerate(zip(*[s.ljust(width) for s in list1])):`, with `width = max(len(s) for s in list1`) and then `None` replaced with `" "`.

Comment: @Timus Good idea! I edited my code. also, we can use `map` instead of list comprehension like this: `map(lambda s: s.ljust(width), list1)`

Comment: this method looks great, I just would like to get it faster on the execution. Do I have to change something on the code you posted on the solution? thanks

Comment: @nuovo2000ita You can use a `map without lambda!` instead of `list comprehension`. it can be faster: [list-comprehension-vs-map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map)

Comment: how would you write the code without lambda in the example above?

Comment: I need to have time and get some benchmarks from the code. but, based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70507442/11100417): you can replace `zip(*[s.ljust(width) for s in list1])` with `zip(*map(lambda s: s.ljust(width), list1))` and get better execution time. @nuovo2000ita

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

list1 = ['one', 'two', 'twin', 'who']

idx =0  #t 
print(Counter(list(zip(*[i for i in list1 if len(i)>3]))[idx]).most_common()[0][0])
```

without importing any libraries

```
list1 = ['one', 'two', 'twin', 'who']

idx =0  #t 
l = list(list(zip(*[i for i in list1 if len(i)>3]))[idx])
print(max(set(l), key = l.count))
```

Comment: There is a problem with `zip`: it consider each item to be in equal length. so for the index 3 it fails

Comment: yeah it only works for the first three index, at the last index it says 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: maybe using a dictionary?

Comment: @HamidRasti you're right, I've changed my answer